# I want a script to select "X8" in the product type and print X8 as o/p

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

These are the two product types, I want my script to run only when "X8" is present in the product type.

product type 1 : Ciara_1x2X8_GENC_64G_Server

Product type 2 : Ciara_15x18X7_LCS_64G_Server

I tried with the grep option "grep X8" , awk and cut.

So I need a generic command to print "X8" ignoring other letters as the product type doesn't have fixed length.

Comment: What are the "letters"? Which one exactly is the "word" and are there two different words you refer? Please clarify with more examples.

Comment: If you want to print `X8` just `echo X8` and ignore your input. If there is something more to know about your problem please edit your question and explain.

Comment: If you want only to print `X8` if it appears in string, you may try something like `echo "your string" | sed -n s/.*X8.*/X8/p'`. Warning: If a line contains more than one `X8`, only one will be printed. The `X8` search here could be better if there are constraints on its position in string.

Comment: This worked sed -n 's/.*X8.*/X8/p', thanks Bruno

Comment: @GuruPrasad, don't forget to accept an answer if it looks OK for you !

Comment: What is the meaning of _print as o/p_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was not very clear, but if the goal is to print `X8` if it appears in a string, a solution could be:

```
sed -n 's/.*X8.*/X8/p'
```

Examples:

```
echo "$string" | sed -n 's/.*X8.*/X8/p'
sed -n 's/.*X8.*/X8/p' input_file
```

To be more general, to output only a string if it appears in a line, it could be:

```
search=X8
sed -n "s/.*\(${search}\).*/\1/p"
```